# Where did Marlin get its name?

Tags: marlin, terminology, history

Does anyone know how the developers of Marlin decided to name it that?

Comment: I saw I'd got an answer, and excitedly opened it up, but then realised that you were backing my question up! I was a bit disappointed that I didn't have an actual answer, but grateful for the backup, nevertheless :-) BTW, I'm quite impressed to see that you've been a member of the forum for over ten years already...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know Erik van der Zalm started Marlin. He is from the Netherlands and Zalm translates to "salmon". One of the design goals of Marlin was to make it faster than the other firmware available at that time. And a marlin is a very fast swimming fish.

Some firmwares developed after Marlin also joined this fish theme: Sailfish, Minnow, ...

Comment: Should I just accept this? Any way to confirm it?

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it probably is totally off-topic, but fun too, so I'll try to get an answer in, before the question gets closed.

The best place to ask would be the [Firmware - Marlin forum](https://reprap.org/forum/list.php?415), on RepRap.org.

The question is there now, [Why was it named Marlin?](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,852947) and I'll update this answer, if/when I get a response...